# ERROR 1062 import sql file with primary and auto increment

Tags: mysql, import

I have a problem, I nedd to restore a sql file, but when I try to do this with `mysql -u user -p --database test < file.sql` I get this error `ERROR 1062 (23000) at line 50: Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'` 
My first attribut is `AUTO_INCREMENT` and `NOT NULL` and `PRIMARY`
I have searched and the probem is in my sql file for my primary key I don't have value I have just simple quote. For example `INSERT INTO log VALUES ('','app1','name','hello')` as you can see my first value is only simple quote, how can I import this sql file without value beacause I have lot of lines in my file...

Definition of the table

```
CREATE TABLE `log` (
  `id_log` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `application` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `module` text NOT NULL,
  `action` text NOT NULL,    
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_log`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=646 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: It would help of you published the table definition for log. Also if the first column in the values clause is mapping to the auto_increment field I would expect a different error - specifically an incorrect integer value error.

Comment: @P.Salmon I've jsut edited my post

Comment: *For example `INSERT INTO log VALUES ('','app1','name','hello')`* Bad news - your dump file is errorneous. It must have `NULL` instead of empty string `''`. Edit your dump file and convert `INSERT INTO log VALUES ('','app1','name','hello')` to `INSERT INTO log VALUES (NULL,'app1','name','hello')`. Or obtain correct dump file.

Comment: There's a dangling comma at the end of the primary key definition - is that a transcription error? doesn't make a difference to your error though,

Comment: @P.Salmon I think OP simply removes some lines from the script...

Comment: Ok I'll replace '' by `NULL` thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would assume `mysql` is trying to cast `''` to an `int` since it is an `AUTO_INCREMENT` field.

It casts it to `0` so for the first entry everything is fine, but on the second one, it already exists and you get the error.

You will have to replace the `''` with actual, unique integer values or remove it altogether and add a columns list.

Comment: @Akina great catch, you are right! Removing it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to rewrite your queries.
The query should look like this:

```
INSERT INTO log(application, module, action) VALUES ('app1','name','hello');
```

This will enter the remaining row in the table and consider the column `id_log` for auto-increment.